# Redirect from inside an iframe in asp.net causes to double back button

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iframe

Ok, i understand title is *not* very clear. I'll explain better now:

I have an iframe with asp.net page inside. To redirect parent from the iframe i use this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "redirector", "window.parent.location.href='myOtherPage.aspx'", True)
```

It works *fine*, perfect on Internet Explorer and Chrome, crappy on firefox and opera. In those two browsers user can see single iframe reloading before the parent reloads, but thats *not* the problem i want to solve.

After a redirect if i hit the Back button on my browser i go back in the old page and bounced forward again. Hitting back again works (with Chrome).
With Internet Explorer no problem, just 1 back works fine.
Firefox and opera bounces me endless times!

I tried to erase the script after execution, so i used this (without any newline):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "redirector", 
    "<script id=""redirector"">
    document.getElementById('redirector').innerHTML = '';
    window.parent.location.href='myOtherPage.aspx';
    </script>", False)
```

but its useless. Redirect still works but same two back button problem.

Any idea on this?

Comment: Can you make the redirect without post back on the iframe ? (using ajax, javascript)

Comment: i need to trigger redirect on some event and server procedure, so if i understand asp.net a little it must have a postback :(

Comment: Try to make the iframe page non cacheable at all.

Comment: i just set non cacheable using info from this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers
but when i hit back button chrome asks for "Confirm Form Resubmission" inside the iframe

Comment: Yes, this is the idea, is ask for that confirm and resubmission. The other is to understand this re-submit and avoid it. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68371/Detecting-Refresh-or-Postback-in-ASP-NET   In general this is not easy.